# Create variable in loop by iterating through dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function that I need to use to operate on rows in two dataframe by their index (the function applies an OLS regression model). The dataframes is populated dynamically via an API call to an external datasource, so contents will vary.

For demonstration, here is the code I have that ingests the dataframes using explicit references.

```
etf = (etfta.loc['SPY'])
equity = (symbolsta.loc['DOCU'])

equity.set_index('date', inplace=True)
etf.set_index('date', inplace=True)
monthly_prices = pd.concat([equity['close'], etf['close']], axis=1)
monthly_prices.columns = ['Equity', 'ETF']
monthly_returns = monthly_prices.pct_change(1)

clean_monthly_returns = monthly_returns.dropna(axis=0)  # drop first missing row
# split dependent and independent variable
X = clean_monthly_returns['Equity']
y = clean_monthly_returns['ETF']

# Add a constant to the independent value
X1 = sm.add_constant(X)

# make regression model 
model = sm.OLS(y, X1)

# fit model and print results
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
print(results.rsquared)
```

This is running the regression on DOCU in the equities dataframe, and SPY in the ETF dataframe. It obviously works fine if I call out the rows I want to use explicitly, but I would like to be able to loop it and perform the function multiple times.

Should be focusing on figuring out how to dynamically create a variable name from the index in my 'symbolsta' dataframe (where `equity = (symbolsta.loc['DOCU']`) is currently hardcoded), or figuring out how to iterated the concat operation that starts the whole thing off.

I would appreciate any thoughts people have on the best way to approach this.

Comment: Can't you run the regression on the whole dataframe and use indicator/dummy variables for the categories ?

Comment: I wish! The issue is that the dataframe contains multiple time series that I need to run it on separately. The model should run on AAPL vs SPY, GOOG vs SPY, NFLX vs SPY, etc -- and AAPL, SPY, GOOG and NFLX are all in a dataframe together. I would separate them out, but they are pulled dynamically.

Comment: Then you can access unique categories with the ``unique`` method and loop over the categories? Put the dataframes in a list, loop over it and catch the regression result for each dataframe ?

Comment: Any time you think you need dynamic variable names, you should just use a dictionary.